# php curl_exec function causes error 500 (FastCGI server error)

Tags: php, apache, cgi, fastcgi

Im trying to run curl_exec and I get error 500. In the error log I have

```
[warn](104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: xxx

[error] Premature end of script headers: myfile.php, referer: xxx
```

I found a suggestion for fix on the internet saying that I have to add this snippet to my vhosts.conf. Since my apache doesn't have vhosts.conf file I added it to httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
      # 5 minutes for IO timeout, default is 40 seconds
      FcgidIOTimeout 300 
</IfModule>
```

but it didn't help. Also I found a suggestion saying that I have to change the permissions of `/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/` but in the `/var/www/cgi-bin/` folder I don't have a cgi_wrapper.

I searched the internet for a couple of hours but I couldn't find anything helpful. Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading php solved this problem.